# Same class than a class of an API exists already

Tags: c#

I am using a class `C` in my code, and I specified to a team delivering a service API to me that the return type of a new function they deliver should be `C`. I'm already using my `C` in my code, and updating their nugget package I also have their `C`. Both `C`'s are rigorously the same (in the definition of the class, they're obviously not in the same namespace).

What should I do ? Should I nevertheless write an obvious wrapper at the lowest possible level ? What is the best practice ?

Comment: So, the problem you're trying to solve is, that you have two classes, that are structurally (and probably functionally) the same, but in different namespaces? And you want to use the class of one namespace in methods that expect the class of the other namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify namespace, like: namespace.your_class_name

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing, but it is awful. Very long namespace

Comment: You can redefine class name in using block. Using OtherC = OtherNamesapce.C.

Answer (score 0):

And what else can you do? Your `C` and their `C` are not the same class, even though they have identical structure. So yes - you have to map between them in both directions when necessary. If your team and team delivering their service is "close enough" (like working at the same company) - best way might be for both teams to use shared assembly with common types, then you will have just one `C`. Other options include for you (as a consumer of their package) to use their `C` type instead of your own (not always possible or desirable of course). You can also use dynamic to treat both types equally, but I certainly won't recommend doing this.